# Chromium error: Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, fonts, chromium

Im using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with latest Chromium (92.0.4515.107)

When I run chromium from Terminal, I see the following warinings:

```
(chrome:25558): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:30:31.111: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3593:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(chrome:25558): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:30:31.111: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4055:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
[25666:25666:0723/213031.187199:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

When I open some of websites (i.e. https://zoon.ru/) all of my chromium windows are closed with following error

`Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

Firefox and Slimjet work ok with this site.

It started today. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It could be the permission issue. Could you try -sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox